# Center of noetherian rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Is it true that the center of a right Noetherian ring (with identity) is always a Noetherian ring ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not true, even under some rather restrictive conditions on the ring. A number of counterexamples, showing that if $R$ is a prime Noetherian PI ring, the center of $R$ need not be Noetherian can be found in Examples 5.1.16 through 5.1.18 of L. Rowen's book *Polynomial identities in ring theory*. Additional examples are sketched in Exercises 1 and 2 of §5.1 in the same book.